# Matching words surrounded by spaces

Tags: php, regex

My requirements are words that:

- Start with char and ends with space
- Or start with space and ends with space

For example:

```
$string = "I am using php regular expressions";
```

Output:

```
$out = ["I", "am", "using", "php", "regular"]; #expected output
```

My effort on solving this:

```
preg_split("/\s+/",$string);
```

Which splits string with spaces but I want output mentioned earlier.

Comment: At [so] you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/)**.

Comment: I tried using `preg_split("/\s+/",$string);`, it split string with spaces but I want output mention in above question.

Comment: Hi, you mean `'expressions'` should not be present in the result array? But what's the reason??

Comment: yes, I want skip word which ends with space.@ankabout

Comment: @JanardhanRam  check this:-https://eval.in/986347

Comment: @AlivetoDie It works fine.

Comment: @JanardhanRam  glad to hear that, but I would recommend you to remove the mark and delete your question because it's actually not serving any useful purpose to anybody. As well as people are posting unnecessary answers just for point sake. Up-to -you.(I am afraid that you will lose more reputation too in near future)

Comment: @JanardhanRam  the answer you marked is actually worked for you?

Comment: According to the example, `expressions` does not end with a space, so what is the rule behind your algorithm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... (1) which starts with char and ends with space and (2) starts with
>   space and ends with space?

First off, your requirements should be moved into question context really. Try to find a better title. However, according to second requirement, below input string should not be matched:

```
string(5) " I\nam"
```

but this should:

```
string(3) " I "
```

Which is not covered by current accepted answer, and if by *char* in title you mean a letter from English alphabet this could be a solution:

```
preg_match_all('~(?i)\b[a-z]\S*(?=\h)~', $string, $matches);
```

Otherwise go with `\S+(?=\h)`

Breakdown:

- `(?i)` Enables case-insensitive flag
- `\S` Matches non-whitespace characters
- `(?=\h)` A positive lookahead. Asserts if following character is a horizontal whitespace

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/QHZK4B/2)